# MaxHeight on RowDefinition with Height=Auto ignored

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

The property MaxHeight seems to be ignored on RowDefinitions with `Height="Auto"`:

Consider the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="100"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
      <ListBoxItem>a</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>b</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>c</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>d</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>e</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>f</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>g</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>h</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>i</ListBoxItem>
      <ListBoxItem>j</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox.Items>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The Grid will be bigger than 100 dip.

**How can I constrain a RowDefinition in its Height?**

Comment: what version of .NET do you use ?

Comment: .NET 4 in the current project. But if there is something new in .NET 4.5 I would like to hear it too.

Comment: By the way just found this little ditty which seems like it will resolve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294368/wpf-grid-layout-panel-with-row-height-set-to-auto?rq=1 i.e. use the 'shortcut' Height="*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be something else. Tried it in a clean Window and the listbox stops at 100 pixels.
Maybe check your styling.

[image]

Comment: Indeed. That's kind of embarassing.

Answer (score 1):

Set the height on the grid to auto and leave maxheight on the rowdefinition.

For Example:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" MinHeight="20" MaxHeight="20"/>
```